# How to add additional plugins in an ejected create react app

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

In an ejected CRA, how to add optional chaining and other features? I am currently using Typescript.

To clarify, the feature is supported in current version of react-script, or CRA. But in the case you already ejected, you still want those features.

Comment: Is it absolutely a requirement that you need to be ejected? The new versions of CRA already support this feature you could just update your react-scripts instead and get it for free

Comment: I ejected the project a long time ago when the feature I needed was not supported. Therefore I had to eject atm. And yes, if I could start a project now, I do not need to eject the project anymore. It simply is a tradeoff to eject or not. I do not think I am the only one in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

In `package.json` under babel, add the following:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
    ]
  }
```